# What does this error mean: ValueError: renderer was passed non-dictionary as value

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

Right now I have a pyramid (python) app with a home page that is reached via this route in the **init**.py file:

```
 config.add_route('home_page', '/')
```

in my views.py file I have:

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']
        body = request.params['body']
        page=Page(name,body)
        DBSession.add(page)
        return HTTPFound(Location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))
```

and in my edit.pt template I have

```
<form action="${save_url}" method="post">
    <textarea name="name" tal:content="page.data" rows="10"
                    cols="60"/><br/>
    <textarea name="body" tal:content="page.name" rows="10"
                    cols="60"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name=form.submitted value="Save"/>
</form>
```

So basically the goal is to have the homepage show this edit.pt template which contains a form for submitting two pieces of information, a page name and page body. Upon submitting the form, the return HTTPFound function should redirect to the view_page created which shows the page name page body on a new permanent url.

I am not sure what I should add after the if statement in my home_page view_config. If the form hasn't been submitted I don't want anything to happen, it should just continue to show that edit.pt template. Right now I am getting an error when I try to visit the home page: ValueError: renderer was passed non-dictionary as value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a condition

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']
        body = request.params['body']
        page=Page(name,body)
        DBSession.add(page)
        return HTTPFound(Location=request.route_url('view_page',pagename=name))

    # form was not submitted here, need to return context
    # ValueError: renderer was passed non-dictionary as value < beacuase you were
    # not returning context for this case before
    return {} # template contenxt here
```

Comment: so in the return function, do I put templates/edit.pt again even though I am already on that template? and Do I call it through return route.request_url('home_page',renderer='templates/edit.pt')

Comment: @BigBoy1337, nope, `templates/edit.pt` should automatically be loaded with the values  you are returning in the dictionary . you could type `{'save_url': 'http://your_url.com'}`

Comment: but http://your_url.com sounds like an independent domain from the rest of the app which is hosted at for ex: http://domain.com. I don't understand how it can do this. How can I generate a url at http://domain.com/custom_url?